# determining the nullity of a $4k\times 4k$ matrix with particular properties, where $k$ is an odd positive integer

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, spectral-graph-theory

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ be nonnegative even integers. Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $4k\times 4k$ matrix, where $k$ is a positive odd integer, such that:

1) The matrix $A$ is symmetric.

2) All of the entries of $A$ consist of linear combinations of the form $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\ldots+c_{n-1}x_{n-1}$, where $c_i=\pm 1$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n-1$.

3) The variables $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ are all nonnegative even integers.

4) All of the diagonal entries are equal to $4kr$, where $r$ is some nonnegative integer.

5) No two expressions in the upper triangular entries are the same; that is, all $\binom{4k}{2}$ of them are distinct.

6) All of the off-diagonal entries are either equal to $0$ or $-4k$; that is, these expressions in terms of the $x_i$'s either equal $0$ or $-4k$.

7) The sum of the entries in each row of $A$ equals $0$. That is, each row has precisely $r$ entries that are equal to $-4k$.

I would like to show that the nullity of $A$ is equal to $1$, $2$, or $4k$, but I do not know if I have enough information. I want to get such a matrix in reduced row echelon form. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: All of the off-diagonal entries are either $0$ or $-4k$, but each row has precisely $r$ entries that are equal to $-1$. Huh?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry about that. I fixed it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: All entries in the strictly upper triangular part are distinct, but each of them is either $0$ or $−4k$. How is that possible?

Comment: @user1551 The expressions in terms of the $x_i$'s are distinct, meaning no two of them have the same sequence of coefficients that take on values $\pm 1$. However, each of these off-diagonal expressions could be equal to $0$ or $-4k$. For example, if $n=5$, we could have $x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4=-4k=-x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4$. The expressions are not the same, but they equal the same value.

Comment: Then how do we know what $c_i$s to use? E.g. when $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(2,4,6,8)$ and $a_{12}=8$. How do we know if $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ is $(1,1,1,-1)$ or $(-1,1,-1,1)$?

Comment: @user1551 That's the thing, I don't know that. This is why I posted this question. This matrix is actually the Laplacian matrix of a graph. I don't know if that helps...